# Design database table for property listing

Tags: database-design, performance, normalization, query-performance

I want to design a database for a listing website, this is the first time I design the database, so I am not sure if I in the correct path. 
Here is the fields that needed in a listing,

1. title - Character
2. pub_date -Timestamp
3. modi_date -Timestamp
4. ex_date - Timestamp
5. desc - Character
6. thumb - Character
7. office_no - Integer
8. mobile_no - Integer
9. email - Character
10. web - Character
11. status - Character
12. state - Character
13. city - Character
14. address - Character
15. postcode - Character
16. lat - float
17. lng - float

The lat (latitude) and lng (longitude) are used for searching, eg, searching nearby listing by comparing the lat and lng. So these fields will be queried often.

My question is should I separate the  *lat* and *lng* into another table (normalization) since these fields will be query a lot. Or I just leave it in one table.

Comment: Using relational databases, since postgresql is in my consideration.

Answer (score 0):

Separating fields "because of performance" is not normalization. Usually having good indexes is the key.

Normalization will help you get rid of redundancy and insert/update/delete anomalies. `lat` and `lng` columns in your table do not seems to suffer from these so moving them to a separate table is not "normalization".

On the other hand, it is still a valid move and may be even beneficial in some use cases - imagine you have a table of cars with GPS locators and keep their actual position in those columns. Moving them to a separate table would allow you to make more updates per second to those columns without affecting the remaining data. But for `SELECT`s you need proper indexing. – https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/64556